# Add namespace Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mime to project?

Tags: import, namespaces

Sorry as I know I must sound stupid here but how do I add/import a namespace to my project? Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mime is what i need but I cannot find the way to add in visual studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common' nuget package first. Then try to import it into your file. I would suggest using [MimeKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit), which is a more sophisticated Mime tool for .NET.

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue, wonder if you could help me with the out come Ive found the post I was reading is 10 years old and the solution provided using this MimeReader library doesnt work... DO you know how to read/parse an EML using the MimeKit class you mentioned?

Comment: Look into this [documentation](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). TL; DR: var message = MimeMessage.Load ("message.eml");